# Excel search for a string and how many times a charactor is in the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

I have a list in excel that contain location but some cell have multiple locations separated by " _ " character for Example "_ Location1 _ Location 2" When there are only 1 location I can use Sumif to search for string and add the numbers next to the cell as shown here
[image]

My problem is not searching for a string but searching for a character in a list and finding how many there are in the cell it find I was going to add the formula in a different cell then the ones shown above

example formula *NOT REAL*

```
=sum(Sumif($A$4:$A$250,"* ~ Location1*",$C$4:$C$250)/Search($A$4:$A$250," ~ "))
```

I know search does work like this but as an example code this is what I imagine

Comment: Are you looking for the formulas for E4:E8 or just E9?

Comment: I want it for all locations so if there 09-10-2016 _ location1 _ location2 for 100 - each location gets 50 added into Row E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to find the sum of each location use this array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D4,$A$4:$A$9)))*($C$4:$C$9/(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("_",$A$4:$A$9)),LEN($A$4:$A$9)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$4:$A$9,"_","")),1))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Enter the formula in E4, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy/fill down.

Then to get the total for all simply sum the rows above.

[image]

---

To do it with regular formulas:

You will need a helper column with the following formula:

```
=C4/(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("_",A4)),LEN(A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"_","")),1))
```

I put mine in Column G.

[image]

Then we can use a simple SUMIF():

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*" & D4 & "*",G:G)
```

[image]